# Java MP3SPI in Applet

Tags: java, mp3, jlayer

I've been struggling with this for the passed few hours but perhaps you guys can give me some help. I've written an application that requires the use of MP3 files. The application runs correctly given the classpath jar files that are said to be included with the MP3SPI that I picked up from javazoom. However, when I try to run the applet I get the Unsupported Audiofile exception. I've modified the archive parameter on the applet tag to include the other 3 jar files,  jl1.0.1.jar, tritonus_share.jar, mp3spi1.9.5.jar but I still get the UnsupportedAudioException. Has anyone had success running the Java MP3SPI in an applet? Thanks in advance.